# Automatic testing of web applications with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

is there any tool out there that i can used to set-up run automatically and i was goggling and i found selenium test runner? there are so many tools out there its hard to figured out which is best

I'm using C# and using MSTest as a test framework and I'm looking forward to see if I can get a way from testing in MSTEST

any help?

Answer (score 0):

This is very subjective question. Every requirement will have its own correct answer. Anyhow I will try to address few requirements and will be updating as I learn more.

If you are automating web app browser tests (sans flash player and silverlight) I would say that selenium is the way to go. There are ways to automate flash and silverlight too, but that is answer for another question.

Selenium is anyways an automation too and your choice will rather is of which test framework to select. So here are few options:

**1. Integrating with CI tools:**

If you want to organize your tests as segregated atomic units and want them to be integrated to some CI server (e.g. TeamCity). I will recommend using [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) to run your selenium tests.

**2. Behavioral Tests**

It is a new trend in the software development and how we test our products. Using behavioral (i.e. business specification) like language. In my experience it is also a very good format to write up acceptance tests. You can use selenium with something like [Nbehave](http://nbehave.org/) or [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/specflownew/)

**3. Centralize Test management and Execution**

Now this might not fit for everyone but I have found [FitNesse](http://www.syterra.com/FitSharp.html) (and its c# binding) to be very useful in maintaining and executing selenium test cases.

Please note this answer may not be right and is certainly not complete given the scope of the question. I have nevertheless tried provide few pointers.

Comment: Thanks Prashant for your reply... I clearly see that there are lot of options but I'm still trying to figured out or rather learning the best tool to use in my particular situation and I'm using Selenium WebDriver using C# to write all my code which interacting with my apps and since I have created dozens of test cases and its time for me to run and I able to run the test case one at a time but that's not very effective and I'm looking a way to make it more automated where I can run when I need without going through opening the Visual Studio and executing all my test cases....

Comment: So, at the end of day I'm looking to replace Visual Studio with some other tool (not sure which one), to run all my test cases, Hope I make sense here.

Comment: @AbuHamzah I will recommend 3rd option (FitSharp) as it seems that you are looking more into end to end tests. For parallel executions you might want to use selenium grid. All in All once you have a dsl / keyword structure ready you can use FitNesse with real elegance and ease